# How to store data from html page to the database?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to store star rating data though HTML page in database using ajax, php and JavaScript. For some reason it's not working, I've posted all the codes below.
Is there any other option to make star rating dynamic in html page.

**here is index.html code**

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div class="py-2">
    <input name="rating" value="0" id="rating_star" type="hidden" postID="1" />
    <span class="overall-rating pl-2" property="aggregateRating" typeof="AggregateRating"> (Average Rating <span id="avgrat" property="ratingValue"></span> Based on <span id="totalrat" property="ratingCount"></span> Reviews) <span id="msg"></span> </span> </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="rating.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**here is rating.js code**

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.rating_widget = function (options) {
var settings = $.extend({
starLength: "5",
initialValue: "0",
imageDirectory: "http://softhubs.website/img/star.png",
inputAttr: null
}, options);
var el = $(this);
var initVal = settings.initialValue;
var avgVal = parseInt($("#avgrat").text());
var ul = $("<ul>");
ul.addClass("rating_widget");
for (var i = 1; i <= settings.starLength; i++) {
if (i <= avgVal) {
ul.append('<li style="background-image:url(' + settings.imageDirectory + '/star.png);background-position:0px -28px;"><span>' + i + '</span></li>');
} else {
ul.append('<li style="background-image:url(' + settings.imageDirectory + '/star.png)"><span>' + i + '</span></li>');
}
}
ul.insertAfter(el);
el.next("ul").children("li").hover(function () {
$(this).parent().children("li").css('background-position', '0px 0px');
var a = $(this).parent().children("li").index($(this));
$(this).parent().children("li").slice(0, a + 1).css('background-position', '0px -28px');
}, function () {
if (initVal == "") {
$(this).children("li").slice(0, initVal).css('background-position', '0px 0px');
} else {
$(this).children("li").css('background-position', '0px 0px');
$(this).children("li").slice(0, initVal).css('background-position', '0px -28px');
}
});
el.next("ul").children("li").click(function () {
var a = $(this).parent().children("li").index($(this));
var attrVal = (settings.inputAttr != '') ? el.attr(settings.inputAttr) : '';
initVal = a + 1;
ajaxPostRating(initVal, attrVal);
});
function ajaxPostRating(val, attrVal) {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'rating.php',
data: 'postID=' + attrVal + '&ratingPoints=' + val,
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
if (data.status == "ok") {
$('#avgrat').text(data.average_rating);
$('#totalrat').text(data.rating_Number);
} else if (data.status == "no") {
$('#msg').text("You are not allow to rate again.");
$("#msg").addClass("text-danger");
} else {}
},
error: function (xhr) {
alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
}
});
}
}
}(jQuery));
$(function () {
$("#rating_star").rating_widget({
inputAttr: "postID"
});
});
```

**here is rating.php code**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
if(!empty($_POST['ratingPoints'])){
$postID = $_POST['postID'];
$ratingNum = 1;
$ratingPoints = $_POST['ratingPoints'];
//Check the rating row with same post ID
$prevRatingQuery = "SELECT * FROM post_rating WHERE post_id = ".$postID;
$prevRatingResult = $db->query($prevRatingQuery);
if($prevRatingResult->num_rows > 0):
$prevRatingRow = $prevRatingResult->fetch_assoc();
$ratingNum = $prevRatingRow['rating_number'] + $ratingNum;
$ratingPoints = $prevRatingRow['total_points'] + $ratingPoints;
//Update rating data into the database
$query = "UPDATE post_rating SET rating_number = '".$ratingNum."', total_points = '".$ratingPoints."', modified = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' WHERE post_id = ".$postID;
$update = $db->query($query);
else:
//Insert rating data into the database
$query = "INSERT INTO post_rating (post_id,rating_number,total_points,created,modified) VALUES(".$postID.",'".$ratingNum."','".$ratingPoints."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";
$insert = $db->query($query);
endif;
//Fetch rating deatails from database
$query2 = "SELECT rating_number, FORMAT((total_points / rating_number),1) as average_rating FROM post_rating WHERE post_id = ".$postID." AND status = 1";
$result = $db->query($query2);
$ratingRow = $result->fetch_assoc();

if($ratingRow){
$ratingRow['status'] = 'ok';
}else{
$ratingRow['status'] = 'err';
}
//Return json formatted rating data
echo json_encode($ratingRow);
}
?>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'post_rating';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
?>
```

**rating.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_rating` (
  `rating_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 = Block, 0 = Unblock'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

it is not working, can anyone guide me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please explain which part is not working (for example, is it the Ajax query or the DB connection?) and share the exact error message if you get any. When you click the element on the HTML page, what is printed in the "Console" and "Network" tabs of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Display - An error occured: 200 OK